# Measuring a view before rendering it and get a remained space (Android)

Tags: android, webview, android-linearlayout, measure

I'm trying to solve this problem in ages but i can't find a solution:
I need to know how much height a webview with some HTML text in it will take in a LinearLayout, if the space occupied doesen't go over screen size i must add another webview with other HTML text in it. I can't figure out how to do it, i tried to call 
measure() but it will give me 0 whatever measurespec i try to use.
Someone knows how to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution for this ? @DLock